# switch case não executa

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
  <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
  <section class="sidebar">
    <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
    <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
      <li class="header">MENU</li>
      <li class="active treeview">
        <a href="?rotina=perfil">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href="?rotina=profile">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          <span>Meu Perfil</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="?rotina=curriculum">
          <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span>Meus Cursos</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="pages/widgets.html">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Meu Curriculum</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>

</aside>

  <?php 

    $tela = "";

    if(!isset($_GET['rotina'])){

      $tela = "homesys.php"; 

   } else {

    $rotina = $_GET['rotina'];

    switch($rotina) {

      case "profile":

        echo $rotina;

        // $tela = "perfil.php"; 
        break;    

      default: 
        $tela = "homesys.php"; 
        break;    

    }

  }

  ?>

  <div class="content-wrapper">

    <?php include_once("../views/$tela");?>

  </div>
```

Quando clico na opção *Meu Perfil*, o `switch case` não executa. Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 2):

É necessário colocar a variável $tela entre chaves. Use o seguinte código: `<?php include_once("../views/{$tela}");?>`.

E outra, o trecho `$tela = "perfil.php";` dentro do case "profile" está comentado no seu código.